# How to find impulse response $h(t)$ from frequency response $H(\omega)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

How can I find the impulse response of [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6ITz.jpg) without using Matlab. I don't want a complete answer. I only need a good way to solve it.

> $$ H(\omega) = \displaystyle{\frac{e^{-6\omega j}}{\displaystyle 3+j\frac{\omega-2}{5}}}$$

Comment: Is that a -6 in the picture?

Comment: yes  upper side is exponential of -6jw